# How to install nvim-html-css neovim plugin in NvChad

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin, plugin-treesitter, nvchad

Neovim plugin: [nvim-html-css](https://github.com/Jezda1337/nvim-html-css)

I don't know lua but I need this plugin installed for bootstrap classes. I have Neovim NvChad lazy.nvim setup. Copy pasting didn't worked so I tried to cut out maybe harmful parts but it still didn't work.

I tried this but it doesnt seem to be working..

```
  require("lazy")
    .setup {
      {
        "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
        opts = {
          sources = {
            -- other sources
            {
              name = "html-css",
              option = {
                enable_on = {
                  "html",
                }, -- set the file types you want the plugin to work on
                file_extensions = { "css", "sass", "less" }, -- set the local filetypes from which you want to derive classes
                style_sheets = {
                  -- example of remote styles, only css no js for now
                  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        "Jezda1337/nvim-html-css",
        dependencies = {
          "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
          "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
        },
        config = function()
          require("html-css"):setup()
        end,
      },
    },
```

Comment: Did the solution provided solved your problem? How can we help you further? If it does may be could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It all the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following lines to the the `plugins` table in the `nvim/lua/custom/plugins.lua` file:

```
  {
      "Jezda1337/nvim-html-css",
      dependencies = {
        "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
        "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
      },
      config = function()
        require("html-css"):setup()
      end,
  },
```

Here is a link to the NvChad documentation about [plugins](https://nvchad.com/docs/config/plugins) it is far from exhaustive but I suppose it will improve over time.

Comment: sadly it didn't worked. pasted that in nvim / lua / custom / plugins.lua and did Lazy sync command but for some reason bootstrap classes still ain't showing up. I do have bootstrap installed via npm and connected to html, but classes still don't show up. I'm not even sure that it even starts. I tried to make current directory directory of the folder I'm working in, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I don't know very well the plugin and what to expect. I could suggest other change but in order to test it would be nice if you could provide an example and an expected behavior.